# Hibernate spatial ServiceConfigurationError

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-spatial

Hey I've been trying to set up Hibernate Spatial to query geographical data stored in PostGreSQL. I getting the following error while trying to run my code.

```
session factory creation failed
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialIntegrator could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:339)
at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:57)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:247)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:73)
at com.handyhome.service.database.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:24)
at com.handyhome.service.database.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:39)
at com.handyhome.service.database.App.main(App.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/spi/BasicServiceInitiator
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.spi.BasicServiceInitiator
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 18 more

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.handyhome.service.database.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:33)
at com.handyhome.service.database.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:39)
at com.handyhome.service.database.App.main(App.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.hibernate.integrator.spi.Integrator: Provider org.hibernate.spatial.integration.SpatialIntegrator could not be instantiated
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:224)
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:181)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:377)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:445)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.loadJavaServices(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:339)
at org.hibernate.integrator.internal.IntegratorServiceImpl.<init>(IntegratorServiceImpl.java:57)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.build(BootstrapServiceRegistryBuilder.java:247)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.<init>(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:73)
at com.handyhome.service.database.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:24)
... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/service/spi/BasicServiceInitiator
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2585)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2885)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:350)
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:373)
... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.service.spi.BasicServiceInitiator
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
... 18 more
```

The code for SessionFactoryCreation

```
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory(){
    try{
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Hibernate Configuration Loaded");
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder
                = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
                .applySettings(configuration.getProperties())
                ;

        logger.log(Level.INFO,"Service registry created");
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());

    }catch (Throwable ex){
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"session factory creation failed",ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
```

It works fine if I remove hibernate-spatial from my dependencies and code. But I really need to use Spatial as my tables contain lat-long data

Comment: me too facing the same issue any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of hibernate are you using?

If you are using 4.2.x or lower in your web container, this method of creating a session factory will fail.

This line is deprecated, but worked for me when I ran into a similar problem:

```
new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: I'm using 4.3.7-final. And I wouldn't want to use deprecated code on production. Any clues on what could be causing this issue? I've searched a lot but couldn't find anything

Comment: What are you using for a Web container? Jboss and Web logic take some extra configuration to make sure they use your webapp lib.

Comment: I'm using Jboss..Also as I said before this issue only arises when I include Hibernate spatial and works fine with that removed.. Is there some extra config required for Spatial?